# Does most inclusive guest invite restriction allows anyone to invite users?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Guest invite restrictions setting in Azure AD external identies, external collaboration settings is:
Anyone in the organization can invite guest users including guests and non admins

Does this mean all users in the SharePoint site can invite other users?

My understanding is that only owners and members(if allowed) can invite.

Comment: I think it depends on your site settings. Check [DisableSharingForNonOwners](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-sposite?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224#-disablesharingfornonowners). Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Also, there is a parameter available with Set-SPOTenant as well. Check: [PreventExternalUsersFromResharing](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-spotenant?view=sharepoint-ps&wt.mc_id=MVP_315224#-preventexternalusersfromresharing).

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP - is the disable sharing for non owners the same as advanced permissions -> access request settings -> `allow members to shar ethe site and individual files and folders`?